# J1939 - CAN BUS - What is ECU and ACU?

Tags: protocol

I have a question about the CAN-bus protocol J1939.
What is ECU and ACU?

Assume that we have three motors that can be controller via J1939. Each motor have it's source address 0x80, 0x81 and 0x83 and destination address 0x22, 0x23 and 0x24.

So what is ECU and ACU here?

Is the ACU = motors and ECU = computer?

Comment: When asking for acronyms, it's necessary to provide the document where these occurred. Otherwise, we can just guess – most three-letter things have multiple meanings. (ECU is very easy to research: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engine_control_unit)

Comment: Guesses: CU = control unit. E = engine and A = aardvark (that was humour).

Comment: ECU is in this case, the CPU/Computer and ACU is the acturator. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ECU = Electronic control unit
ACU = Airbag control unit

Comment: Hi! Thank you. But ACU was acturatur control unit =) BR!